How can one output GPAW energy densities after a SCF calculation?
I'm looking to obtain the final energy densities in real space of the terms that compose the total energy in GPAW:
$$E = E_{kin} + E_{coul} + E_{xc} + E_{zero}$$
I can get the XC energy density by using the function calculate in the functional.py.
How can I get the energy densities in real space of the other terms?
